# Stopping jQuery Mobile styling overriding mine?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a menu that uses its own styling but jQuery Mobile css keeps overriding my menu styling. I wished they would limit there styling to ui-body. Is there a way to prevent jQuery Mobile css from overriding my menu styling? I have tried moving my styling before and after the jQuery Mobile include link but no help. also have tried data-role="none", no help. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using !important to stop JQ Mobile from overriding your styles.

EX:

```
font-weight:normal !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it would help if you supply example code but I'm assuming the following is happening.

Sample html:

```html
<div class="my-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#"></li>
        <li><a href="#"></li>
        <li><a href="#"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery mobile probably has a class set as follows:

```css
<style>
    a {color:blue;}
</style>
```

To override this you need to be more specific with your classes:

```css
<style>
    div.my-menu ul li a {color:red;}
</style>
```

Comment: did not help. I think jQuery Mobile goes through the hole page and rewrites it. I don't think there is a way to do it with css because jQuery Mobile will just over write any changes you make. data-role="none" should do it but there must be a bug.